# How can i compare two timestamp in sql?

Tags: mysql

I need to compare two date (the type in db is TIMESTAMP) in my db (MySQL). 
Something like this: (this query in very very simplified because I need this answer only)

```
SELECT count(id) as count FROM table WHERE data1 > data2
```

`data1` and `data1` are two TIMESTAMP columns in my db.

I do this query through PHP, so I have all the features of PHP available.
Thanks for your help

Comment: So what is the problem, doesn't it work, do you get an error, etc.?

Comment: that query seems ok as it is

Comment: @Andrea Which type of comparision you have done?

Comment: Please explain your issue..

Comment: is this expression correct?? SELECT count(id) as count FROM table WHERE data1 > data2

Comment: @Andrea yes it is correct, why don't you try it on your database.

Answer (score 1):

The expression itself looks ok. If you have trouble maybe is due to backticks.

Try:

`` SELECT count(id) as count FROM table WHERE `data1` > `data2` ``

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias so that you don't encounter naming issues.

`SELECT count(t.id) as count FROM table t WHERE t.data1 > t.data2`